# How to show that the integral is convergent without actually evaluating it?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> $$ \int _ 0 ^ { + \infty } \frac 1 { \sqrt { 1 + x ^ 8 } } \ \mathrm d x $$

I have a hint that says there is no elementary way to evaluate this integral. So I am supposed to bound this integrand by a simpler function and use the following fact without proof:

> Let $ f : [a,+\infty) \to \mathbb R $ be a bounded and increasing function. Then $ \lim _ { x \to \infty } f ( x ) $ exists.

I specifically don't understand what it means to bound the integrand by a simpler function. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by noting that the existence of the proposed integral is equivalent to the existence of the integral $\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^8}} dx$. Then, since
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^8}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^8}} = \frac{1}{x^4},
$$

the convergence of $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^4} dx$ implies the convergence of our integral.

Answer (score 1):

Just to take a slightly different approach, if we can establish that

$${1\over\sqrt{1+x^8}}\le{2\over1+x^2}$$

for all $x$, then we have

$$\int_0^\infty{dx\over\sqrt{1+x^8}}\le2\int_0^\infty{dx\over1+x^2}=\pi$$

To establish the key inequality, note that

$${1\over\sqrt{1+x^8}}\le{2\over1+x^2}\iff1+2x^2+x^4\le4+4x^8\iff 4x^8-x^4-2x^2+3\ge0$$

and

$$4x^8-x^4-2x^2+3\ge
\begin{cases}
0-1-2+3=0\quad&\text{if }|x|\le1\\
4x^8-x^8-2x^8+3=x^8+3\ge0\quad&\text{if }|x|\ge1
\end{cases}$$

The only advantage (if any) of this approach is that it uses a single formula for the bounding function, rather than one formula for $x\le1$ and another for $x\ge1$. But doing so, of course, comes at the expense of a slightly tricky verification of a polynomial inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$ \frac{1} { \sqrt{1+ x^{8} } } \sim \frac{1} { x^4 }, x \to +\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

For $x > 1$,
\begin{align*}
  0 < x^8 &< x^8 + 1 < \infty  \\
  0 < x^4 = \sqrt{x^8} &< \sqrt{x^8 + 1} < \infty  \\
  \infty > \frac{1}{x^4} &> \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^8+1}} > 0  \text{.}
\end{align*}
So, $$  0 = \int_1^\infty 0 \,\mathrm{d}x < \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^8 + 1}} \,\mathrm{d}x < \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^4} \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}  $$
The right-hand $p$-integral is convergent, so $\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^8 + 1}} \,\mathrm{d}x$ is convergent.

For $0 \leq x \leq 1$, \begin{align*}
    1 &\leq x^8+1 \leq 2  \\
    1 = \sqrt{1} &\leq \sqrt{x^8+1} \leq \sqrt{2}  \\
    1 = \frac{1}{1} &\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^8+1}} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \text{.}  \\
\end{align*}
So,
$$  1 = \int_0^1 1 \,\mathrm{d}x \geq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^8+1}} \,\mathrm{d}x \geq \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \text{.}  $$
This shows the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^8+1}} \,\mathrm{d}x $ is convergent.

Therefore, $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^8+1}} \,\mathrm{d}x$ is convergent.